# Get entire subgraph starting from one node in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to extract (retrieve) all the nodes and relationships in a graph starting from a specific node.

I have tried something like:

```
MATCH (n:Resource {resource_id: "R208997"})
MATCH p=(n)-[*]->(m) 
RETURN p
```

This fetches all the paths from the node I have, but It is not really what I want.

What I want is to have a table showing the following:

```
From | Rel. | To
----------------
x    | r    | y
z    | r2   | g
```

I am using version: 3.4.12 Community edition of Neo4J, and the data that I'm working on looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Give an example of the data on which your query is not working correctly.

Comment: @stdob-- I have included a visualization of the data that I'm working on

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is to use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), we have some path expander procs for doing this efficiently.

You can use [apoc.path.subgraphAll()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#path-expander) for this, YIELDing relationships which you can alias accordingly:

```
MATCH (n:Resource {resource_id: "R208997"})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {relationshipFilter:'>'}) YIELD relationships
UNWIND relationships as rel
RETURN startNode(rel) as from, type(rel) as rel, endNode(rel) as to
```

If you need to output only certain properties from the nodes rather than the node itself, then you can modify that in your RETURN accordingly.

Comment: how does this work with pure Cypher (not use apoc)?